# Perl tool chain using jenkins envinject variables

Tags: perl, jenkins

I have written some Perl code and using Perl tool chain. Here is my code

```
my $sourcedir = $ENV{"SOURCE"};
my $targetdir = $variables{'DRIVE_LOCATION'};
my $artifactdir = $ENV{"ARTIFACT"};
my $appname = $ENV{"APPNAME"};
my $filetype = $ENV{"FILETYPE"};
my $ver = $ENV{versionName};
print "targetdir $target_dir \n";
my ( $buildno, $ver ) = @ARGV;
$Artifactname = "Android_{$app_name}.$ver";
print "artifact $Artifactname\n";
mkdir $Artifactname;
opendir( my $DIR, $sourcedir ) || die "can't opendir $source_dir: $!";
my @files = readdir($DIR);
foreach my $t ( sort grep( /^.*\.$filetype/, @files ) )
{
   if ("$sourcedir/$t")
   {
      copy "$sourcedir/$t", "./$Artifactname/$t";
      print " pathname $artifactdir/$Artifactname \n ";
      dircopy( "$artifactdir/$Artifactname", "$targetdir/$Artifactname" );
   }
}
closedir($DIR);
```

when i run this code i am getting the below error

```
Use of uninitialized value $app_name_ in concatenation (.) or string at
Scripts/perl/copyfiles.pl line 29 (#3)
 Use of uninitialized value $ver in concatenation (.) or string at
Scripts/perl/copyfiles.pl line 29 (#3)
```

Also not able to create the directory with the values. please can anyone help with this. 
`my $ver = $ENV{versionName} // versionName` is environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

So first off:

```
$Artifactname = "Android_{$app_name}.$ver
```

But you declare `$appname`. The error message tells you this.

And then - `$ver` you read out of `@ARGV` - it clobbers what you set it to from `%ENV`. But you never check if there is an `@ARGV` containing data, so chances are - no arguments are passed, and thus this value is also undefined.

```
my ( $buildno, $ver ) = @ARGV;
```

(And that `my` redeclares it to, so that'll error as well).

If you want to do a default, then:

```
my ( $buildno, $ver ) = @ARGV;
$ver //= $ENV{'versionName'}; #conditional assignment.
```

Also - given you're doing an `opendir`/`readdir`/`grep` have you considered just using `glob` instead?

```
foreach my $filename ( glob ( "$sourcedir/*.$filetype") ) {
```

As this will also give you full paths.

Comment: Thanks, For loop looks good to me. But how can i achieve the above code. '$Artifactname = "Android_{$app_name}.$ver'  $app-name menioned in my  jenkins conf page for example APPNAME=Test. and also versionName i set as env variable using the following command 'set /p versionName=<versionName.txt' this versionName is assigned to $ver, dont know how to do that, please can u advise on this.

Comment: @krishna: Your comment looks a lot like you are asking a new question. Probably best to post that as a completely new question.